# Archlinux effect of downgrading package

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

I'm using `v8` version `3.26.x`, but somehow to compile another package, it requires older version `3.19.x`. I'm done downgrading the `v8` and done compiling that package:

```
v8 3.19.18.4-1
```

What is the effect of downgrading package? would it break something that depends on it? such as `chromium`/`google-chrome`?

Comment: [Partial upgrades are unsupported](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported)... What is the package you are compiling, and why?

Comment: To compile `couchbase`, it depends on older version of `v8`

Comment: `v8` is not a dependency of `chromium`, so it might not be an issue. I'd still try and build against up-to-date versions, though...

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question more directly. Yes downgrading can cause screwey problems with other software. And what you downgrade may not fit with dependencys that are not downgraded. Which is part of why its not supported. While I find downgrading necessary at times it can be problematic....